# Get current url excluding Included file names

Tags: php, css, include, filepath

I have a file named `administrator1.php` and inside it `test.php` is included. So code inside `administrator1.php` is

```
 <?php include 'test.php'; ?>
```

I have a dynamic navigation menu inside `test.php`. Code is

```
<?php 
$menu = array(
  'users'  => array('text'=>'USERS',  'url'=>'administrator1.php'),
  'createProfile'  => array('text'=>'CREATE PROFILE',  'url'=>'administrator2.php'),
  'payment' => array('text'=>'PAYMENTS', 'url'=>'administrator3.php'),
  'defense' => array('text'=>'DEFENSE', 'url'=>'administrator4.php'),
  'progressReport' => array('text'=>'PROGRESS REPORT', 'url'=>'administrator5.php'),
);

class Nav {
  function GenerateMenu($items) {
    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach($items as $item) {
      if(stristr(__FILE__,$item['url'])===FALSE) { 
        $html .= "<li><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}</B></span> </a> </li>";
      }
      else {
        $html .= "<li class='active'><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}.nnn</B></span> </a></li>";
      }
    }
  $html .= "</ul>";
  return $html;
}};

echo Nav::GenerateMenu($menu); 
?>
```

And I have called the `Nav` method inside the same file.

Problem here is, the whole navigation bar will be printed, but selected item's ('USERS') CSS class `active` will not be called. But if I replace this whole code in `administrator1.php` file without including a `test.php` file it works fine. So I guess it is a problem to file path of the included file. And is it because I have used `__FILE__` to get current path? Then how can I get current file path excluding included files names in the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calling the static function we can use `::` operator. But for accessing the non-static member of the class you should make the object, like -

```
$nav_ob = new Nav();
echo $nav_ob->GenerateMenu($menu);
```

And there s problem, when you are creating array -

```
$menu = array(
  'users'  => array('text'=>'USERS',  'url'=>'administrator1.php'),
  'createProfile'  => array('text'=>'CREATE PROFILE',  'url'=>'administrator2.php'),
  'payment' => array('text'=>'PAYMENTS', 'url'=>'administrator3.php'),
  'defense' => array('text'=>'DEFENSE', 'url'=>'administrator4.php'),
  'progressReport' => array('text'=>'PROGRESS REPORT', 'url'=>'administrator5.php'), //Here
);
```

Comma after the last element. It should be -

```
$menu = array(
  'users'  => array('text'=>'USERS',  'url'=>'administrator1.php'),
  'createProfile'  => array('text'=>'CREATE PROFILE',  'url'=>'administrator2.php'),
  'payment' => array('text'=>'PAYMENTS', 'url'=>'administrator3.php'),
  'defense' => array('text'=>'DEFENSE', 'url'=>'administrator4.php'),
  'progressReport' => array('text'=>'PROGRESS REPORT', 'url'=>'administrator5.php')
);
```

**UPDATED**

```
<?php 
$menu = array(
  'users'  => array('text'=>'USERS',  'url'=>'administrator1.php'),
  'createProfile'  => array('text'=>'CREATE PROFILE',  'url'=>'administrator2.php'),
  'payment' => array('text'=>'PAYMENTS', 'url'=>'administrator3.php'),
  'defense' => array('text'=>'DEFENSE', 'url'=>'administrator4.php'),
  'progressReport' => array('text'=>'PROGRESS REPORT', 'url'=>'administrator5.php')
);

class Nav {
  function GenerateMenu($path, $items) {
    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach($items as $item) {
      if(stristr($path,$item['url'])===FALSE) { 
        $html .= "<li><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}</B></span> </a> </li>";
      }
      else {
        $html .= "<li class='active'><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}.nnn</B></span> </a></li>";
      }
    }
  $html .= "</ul>";
  return $html;
}}; 
?>
```

And on each administrator.php file after including the above php file call the method like -

```
$nav_ob = new Nav();
echo $nav_ob->GenerateMenu(__FILE__, $menu);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @dnk remove the comma after the last value in the array. That's the problem.

Comment: removed! still class active is not called for the selected item 'USER' . But when it is replaced in the administrator1.php file without including test.php file it works!

Comment: Is it something to do with file path and `__FILE__` ?

Comment: @dnk yes, here `__FILE__` will return the path of `test.php`

Comment: how can i get the path as administrator1.php?

Comment: Just create the object in administrator1.php and call the method there. wait i will update the answer

Comment: Thank you your help! But now the navigation menu will not be printed. Since you have asked to call the Nav method in administrator1.php file i tried using `echo Nav::GenerateMenu($menu);` too. But both ways are not working. No menu bar will be printed.

Comment: @dnk make a call using `echo $nav_ob->GenerateMenu(__FILE__, $menu);` because i have modified the method prototype.

Comment: @dnk and as i said earlier, you can't make a call to non-static member without creating object, so this is not a problem.

Comment: Still no navigation bar will be printed!

Comment: what error you are getting? try to check with
`ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Navigation bar will be printed now, Sorry for the previous mistake. But isn't there a way to call it in the test.php file because navigation bar will be printed at the bottom of the page, even after the footer. (I have some more code in test.php) And all the css styles are gone. Will be printed as a small list at the bottom. Isn't there a way to fix this by calling nav method in test.php file itself?

Comment: I replaced `__FILE__` in previous code with `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` and it worked. Thank you very much for the help given! :)

Comment: Yes this is also good to have `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` .. wc :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! 
Replaced `__FILE__` with  `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. So the code is;

```
class Nav {
 function GenerateMenu($items) {
 $html = "<ul>";
 foreach($items as $item) {
  if(stristr($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],$item['url'])===FALSE) { 
    $html .= "<li><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}</B></span> </a> </li>";
  }
  else {
    $html .= "<li class='active'><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}.</B></span> </a></li>";
  }
}
$html .= "</ul>";
return $html;
}};
$nav_ob = new Nav();
echo $nav_ob->GenerateMenu($menu);
```

Now it works as i wanted! Thank you everyone for the help given!